# How to center DIV within a DIV?

Tags: html, css, footer, 960.gs

I have a footer which I am currently building.

I want to be able to center the 4 divs in the footer (like first paragraph or the 5 icons (which have failed to render)). What is the best way to do this?

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8q5ek/3/

CSS:

```
#insidefooter, #disclaimer {
max-width: 960px;
min-width: 960px;
margin-left: 25%;
margin-right: auto;
}
#footer {
color: #C9C9C9;
min-width: 1500px;
background-color: #2d2d2d;
list-style: none;
height: 450px;
background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/yb7j6PD.png);
background-repeat:repeat;
}
#insidefooter {
margin-top: 20px;
text-align: center;
}
/*settings for social media buttons*/
 #insidefootertermsplusbuttons li {
display: inline;
color: #C9C9C9;
}
#insidefooterone1 h5, #insidefootertwo1 h5, #insidefooterthree1 h5, #insidefooterfour1    h5 {
text-align:left;
margin-bottom: 0;
padding-bottom: 0;
color:#FFFFFF;
padding-left: 0px;
}
#insidefooterone1 li, #insidefootertwo1 li, #insidefooterthree1 li, #insidefooterfour1 li {
list-style: none;
text-align: left;
margin-left: 0;
color: #C9C9C9;
padding: 0;
}
#insidefooterone1 ul, #insidefootertwo1 ul, #insidefooterthree1 ul, #insidefooterfour1 ul {
list-style: none;
text-align: left;
padding-left: 0px;
padding-right: 0;
color: #C9C9C9;
overflow: hidden;
}
#disclaimer {
margin-top: 20px;
font-size: 9px;
text-align: center;
margin-bottom: 0;
}
#disclaimer p {
text-align:center;
color: #C9C9C9;
}
.ul_links {
overflow: auto;
display: inline-block;
min-width: 700px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved your problem.
So I played around with your code a lot, did many changes, here is the result:

http://jsfiddle.net/rYjS9/7/

The actual trick was using `display: inline-block;` and `margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;` and a couple of other stuff I have changed, as you can see from the jsfiddle. ;)

Regards

Comment: Unfortunately did not work. A few suggested similar method to yours which probably does work in most scenarios, but due to the 960 grid system it failed to work.

Comment: Send me a link to your website and i can understand your code better :)

Comment: The footer should have position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
Does that work?

Comment: Here is the link dchost.co.uk. The website was build on http://960.gs/ which is a really awesome framework. It's my first attempt to ever building a website so don't judge the noobie code :)

Comment: No problem, we are here to help you :) Isn't the problem fixed?

Comment: Yes but it won't let me select my answer for another to days... how else can I close the question?

Comment: you can close your question at the bottom of your question: share, adit, delete and flag. ;)

Comment: i still try to solve it and contact you via the support

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I've voted your question so at least it's known it has been answered :)

Comment: instead of going through the support (if you are referring to the website) can you go through ben@dataconnectivity.co.uk, otherwise all of my work colleagues will receive the email and won't have a clue what the message is about!

Answer (score 0):

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8q5ek/5/)

remove

```
/* #insidefooter, #disclaimer {
    max-width: 960px;
    min-width: 960px;
    margin-left: 25%;
    margin-right: auto;
}*/
```

Add #footer in

```
margin 0 auto;

#footer {
    color: #C9C9C9;
    min-width: 1500px;
    background-color: #2d2d2d;
    list-style: none;
    height: 450px;
    background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/yb7j6PD.png);
    background-repeat:repeat;
    margin 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply but did not solve issue since it distorted everything on the footer :(. But I did manage to figure it out (answer is below) which turns out modifying the position variable on the ul_links class was all that was needed (without changing too much code)

Answer (score 0):

Remove below code and

```
#insidefooter, #disclaimer {
    max-width: 960px;
    min-width: 960px;
    margin-left: 25%;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Paste below code

```
#insidefooter, #disclaimer {
    max-width: 960px;
    min-width: 960px;
    margin 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply but did not solve issue since it distorted everything on the footer :(. But I did manage to figure it out (answer is below) which turns out modifying the position variable on the ul_links class was all that was needed (without changing too much code)

Answer (score 0):

Managed to figure it out. Thank you for your time and answers, but unfortunately, all of them failed to resolve to issue due to using a grid system (which was causing footer to distort).

What I needed to do was change the ul-links adding a position: relative and manually specifying it's position:

```
.ul_links{
   overflow: auto;
   display: inline-block;
   min-width: 700px;
   position: relative;
   left: 120px;
}
```

It's probably not the best nor tidiest way to do it, but it solved the issue.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8q5ek/6/)

Comment: @Pete yes I tested it on the live website and it did not like it. For some reason my footer seems to be float dependable and if I removed the float it would seriously distort everything. I took a screen shot which I was going to show you http://i.imgur.com/kLSfGve.png .